# Indexes on string fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I need a collection to store rendered formulas. I've done this:

```
class FormulaImage(Document):

    formula = me.StringField(primary_key=True)
    image = me.ImageField()
```

I am in doubt about using possibly large strings as index. Should I add a formula hash field and use it as primary index? Or MongoDB does this by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some restrictions on creating MongoDB indexes. The one that will affect you is this one:

> The total size of an index entry, which can include structural
>   overhead depending on the BSON type, must be less than 1024 bytes.

So if you're not sure what the size of your strings will be, you're best option is to create a separate hash over that string and use index on that column.

More details on index restrictions [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#indexes)